# mail php variables (wordpress environment)

Tags: php, wordpress, email, registration

I have been trying to make this code work, on the Login/Register page, with no luck so far. Once you press the "Register" button, the user should get access + an email with website credentials. So far, access is working good (it is being granted). Email is sent successfully with message, but user's login and password are not being retrieved (showed on email body). This is my code:

```
//script send email to new user
<?PHP
$user_login = wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $_POST['user_login'] );
$user_pass1 = wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $_POST['user_pass1'] );
$user_email = wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $_POST['user_email'] );
$from1="team@website.com" ;
$subject1="Login and Password" ;
$message1= "<p>Welcome to my site.</p><p>Your credentials are:</br><b>Login:</b>$user_login</br><b>Password:</b>$user_pass1</p><p>Thank you for being part of our growing community.</p>" ;
$headers1 = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n" ;
$headers1 .= 'from:'.$from1."\r\n";

      mail ($user_email, $subject1, $message1, $headers1) ;
?>
```

This is what I get on the email (screenshot on link) https://www.dropbox.com/s/0isxnt5rwcdn9ko/screenshot.png?dl=0

Many thanks in advance for your help. Have a great holidays.

Comment: did you try leaving out the `wp_filter...` stuff?

Comment: Besides, there's a typo: `$from1="team@website.com";` and later: `$headers1 .= 'from:'.$from."\r\n";` Shouldn't that be **`$from1`**

Comment: Just updated code. My original code had $from1, don't know why I had the typo. User's email still not showing user's login nor password. Thanks

Comment: Did you try to inspect the value of `$_POST['user_login']` and `wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $_POST['user_login'] )`?

Comment: I am sorry I am new to php. I have been learning the language for a couple of month already. I am not sure I understood what you mean with "Inspect the value". Same variable is being used to create user on data base, and the user is being created, so the variables are storing indeed the data. Would you mind helping this newbie with the "Value inspection" you are talking about? Many thanks in advance

Comment: @Banzay Am I coding the variable retrieve right? I have seen it like this: `$message = "This is your Login".$user_login;`   Not sure if I am doing it right.

Comment: You can try to assign `$message1="user_login: ".$user_login.", POST[user_login]: ".$_POST['user_login']` and you'll see wether `$_POST` variables are set and is `wp_filter_nohtml_kses` working properly. This way you can check other variables: what you put and what you get.

Comment: It would be great if you show here a submit form html-code.

Comment: @Banzay I really appreciate your help. Indeed the variable was returning no value at all. I had the html-code within a function, and I was trying to call the variables from outside the function. I just included the email script inside the fuction when a new user register and that fixed the problem. Again thanks for your help and patience